# Как сформировать запрос к базе данных

Tags: запрос

Как сформировать запрос к базе данных на обновление доп. поля в таблице dle_post, где xfields - поле в таблице, а poster -  значение доп. поля. Все доп. поля находятся в одной колонке xfields поля и как вытащить нужное доп. поле, например poster для перезаписи?

Проблема в том, что в таблице -  dle_post находится поле - xfields в котом находятся разные значения доп. полей (не одно). И от сюда вопрос, как при помощи запроса попасть в таблицу -  dle_post в поле - xfields, в котором находится именно значение poster.

Comment: Что значит доп.поля? Какая субд, каков тип поля xfields? Обычные колонки не имеют никаких доп.полей. Необходимо уточнить с чем имеем дело.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dle_post SET xfields = 'новое значение' WHERE xfield = 'старое значение'
```